# 後に【あとに】or【のちに】?

Tags: readings

In the sentence  その事は又後に相談しましょう。
I was wondering whether it is 【あとに】or【のちに】, that is to say...
その こと は また **のちに** そうだん しましょう。  or perhaps
その こと は また **あとに** そうだん しましょう。
*We will talk about it another time.*
Happily, I found an answer here,
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/9500/revisions
"「後{のち}に」sounds literary, so we rather use 「てから」/「後{あと}で」in daily conversation."
Can I assume that answer applies to the sentence above, too, or am I overlooking some issue?

Comment: The linked answer also says `③カレと[別]{わか}れた[後]{のち}に ... (I think ③ is also read as「～あとに～」.)`